# How to add hyperlink to Awesome-CV template?

Tags: hyperref, templates, awesome-cv

I use [Awesome-CV template](https://github.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV) where an e-mail adress is added by `\email{user@mail.com}`.

The body of the command is as follows:

```
% Defines writer's email (optional)
% Usage: \email{<email adress>}
\newcommand*{\email}[1]{\def\@email{#1}}
```

How do add a hyperlink to the e-mail adress? I tried 
`\href{mailto:\email{user@mail.com}}{user@mail.com}` but there are many errors when I try to compile.

Comment: the basic syntax would be `\href{mailto:user@mail.com}{user@mail.com}`, but as far as I remember, the `\email` macro is a shorthand for this so you should just use `\email{user@mail.com}`

Comment: @ebo And you're totally correct. I did also not fully get what the user wants.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use email as you would normally and then a

```
\hypersetup{colorlinks}
```

directly after you loaded the class. This would e.g. color the links. If you want boxes instead use `pdfborder={1 1 1}` or something adjusted to your liking.

See the `hyperref` manual for more information.

---

*Update:* As you did not understand how I meant this (following code from Overleaf template):

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{awesome-cv}
\hypersetup{colorlinks}

\name{Byungjin}{Park}
\position{Software Engineer{\enskip\cdotp\enskip}Security Expert}
\address{246-1002, Gwangmyeongmayrouge Apt. 86, Cheongna lime-ro, Seo-gu, Incheon-si, 404-180, Rep. of KOREA}

\mobile{(+82) 10-9030-1843}
\email{posquit0.bj@gmail.com}
\homepage{www.posquit0.com}
\github{posquit0}
\linkedin{posquit0}

...
```

Just proceed as usual!

---

*Update 2:* If you did not mean anything with emphasis: The hyperlink is already there, even if you just use `\email`. It just won't be shown as the class uses the `hyperref` option `hidelinks`.

Comment: Thanks, but my aim is to use `\email{user@mail.com}` because it adds e-mail to the right dimension of a page and it also adds a github icon. I know it is possible, becuase I have already done it but I lost the contents of my CV due to hardware error.

Comment: @menteith That's what you shall use! Just put this command after your documentclass and you will notice the difference.

Comment: `The hyperlink is already there, even if you just use \email` Are you sure? I switched from Adobe Reader to Foxit PhantomPDF and perhaps Foxit won't show links.

Comment: YES! As I said in my answer it just uses the hyperref option `hidelinks` and that causes links to not show up. You can look it up in the sources, if you want.

Comment: Well, i like templates. :-p

Comment: @Johannes_B And I like the users that question it (the right way)...